# find the table size on IBM netezza sql database from Aginity workbench on win 7

Tags: sql, database, windows-7, netezza

I need to find a table size on IBM netezza sql database from Aginity workbench on win 7.

I used this

```
 SELECT  * FROM _V_TABLE
 where tablename = 'my_table_name'
```

But, no information about table size.

I right-clicked the table name in Aginity, but, nothing came out.

Any help would be appreciated.

thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try this query.

```
select used_bytes/pow(1024,3) as used_gb, *
from _v_table_storage_stat
where tablename = 'my_table_name'
```

Answer (score 3):

In Aginity (v2.1.181.6948), right click on your database.  Select 'Show Tables Size'.  The new window that appears will have table names, owner, created, bytes allocated, bytes used, etc.